# Almost impossible to focus TextInput in React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using  React Native TextInput on Android. The problem is that you have to press it multiple times for it to work .. and I also noticed that sometimes the cursor blinks once (as if it worked and the keyboard is going to appear) but then it disappears and nothing happens

```
<TextInput
            style={{
              fontFamily: 'greycliff-cf-regular',
              fontSize: 14,
              height: 32,
              paddingTop: 0,
              marginTop: 6,
              flex: 1,
              color: '#fff',
            }}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            autoCorrect={false}
            onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
            placeholder={'some text'}
            value={this.state.currentInput}
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

**I had similar issue once and solved it by removing the padding from style.**

Hope it helps to you too,also if doesn't please provide a photo or details on what the problem is which you are facing.